# How to display in a text field a date with format "dd/mm/YYYY"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to display in a text field a date with format "dd/mm/YYYY". 
I tried include the following in en.yml:

```
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%d/%m/%Y"
```

and

```
<%= f.date_field :date, value: t(:date)%>
```

But does not works.

Also I tried add a file called date_format.rb in `initializers` folder with the code:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%d/%m/%Y"
```

But nothings happens

How can I do this?

Note: I'm using Rails 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try localizing the date with:

```
l(date)
```

and to get the shorter version:

```
l(date, format: :short)
```

In case you need to be able to display and edit a date in a form, you could try [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) or [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) and then display the date field:

```
<%= f.input :date, as: :date %>
```

This should automatically convert your date in the default format for the current locale.

Comment: For `f.text_field :date, value: l(:date,  format: :short)` I get the error `Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. :date given.`

Comment: Inside the form you should use `l(f.object.date, format: :short)`

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
t.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not `t` (I18n.translate) you should use.

It's `l` (I18n.localize) instead.

So just do `<%= f.date_field :date, value: l(f.object.date)%>`

Answer (score -1):

```
<%= f.date_field :date, value: t.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")%>
```